# How to complete a plus-minus operation in Java?

Tags: java

Is there an operation for plus-minus in Java?

If not, then what's the most efficient way to do so?

Let's say you got two variables, `a = 4` and `b = 3`, what I want is to be able to do `a ± b` which would return two values, 7 and 1, because 4 + 3 is 7 and 4 - 3 is 1.

Comment: what is plus-minus, which one should java do? in math ± stand for general thing, which in spec thing it maybe + or -

Comment: Call "[Math.abs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)"?

Comment: pst: I re-worded it in English. elbek: That's what I want, + AND -, and the operation would return two values. paulsm4: From what I understand that returns the absolute value.

Comment: @45lbplates There is no standard Type/support in Java to represent imaginary numbers (or other complex mathematical types/representations). There are a number of libraries. Consider adding some *real* pseudo-code of a *real problem* of how such an operator might be used: that is, what is the end-goal? Otherwise, `a_plus = a + b; a_minus = a - b; ..` (I believe a "*symbolic algrebra library*" might be of interest; try google for hints.)

Comment: In hindsight, it seems ridiculous to expect Java to be able to take two terms, compute them with two different operations, and return two values. What I wanted was a 4 ± 3, and it would return 7 and 1.

Comment: @45lbplates By itself, yes .. although there *are* (domain-specific) languages that allow this, and there *are* libraries in Java that can represent this.

Comment: @45lbplates Cool thought, but that just isn't the way ints and floats work.  Plus, it could spiral out of control quickly (±1±2±4±8 has 16 values!)

Comment: I see pst. I'm beginning to understand Java now. If I want a ± 'operation', I can import libraries, but it's not an operation that comes with Java.

Comment: Just print a + b and a - b

Answer (score 2):

plus-minus is not an operation, it is a symbol.  If you just want to include it in a string you can use Unicode \u00B1 such as:

System.out.println("sqrt(9) = \u00B1 3");

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Wiki article carefully you'll note that plus-minus is not an operation.  It's a sign used in engineering and mathematics (amongst other fields) to indicate that a value could be positive or negative.

For example the the square root of 4 is not actually 2, it's "plus-minus 2", because (+2)^2 and (-2)^2 are both 4.

It's also used in tolerances and errors in measurements such as "The part you're paking must be 100mm plus-minus 0.5mm in length" (the part must be between 99.5mm and 100.5 mm in length).

Because variables can only have one value a plus-minus token/keyword/whatever doesn't make much sense.  You could however use a data structure and associate methods appropriate to the application to keep track of these kinds of values.

Comment: In the wikipedia article in the shorthand section, it shows how in the quadratic equation the plus-minus 'sign' adds AND subtracts the following term to make two new values. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, but it's not actually an operator.  It's just a shorthand to save having to write out the equation twice.  It's possible to write a method (operation) that would do this, but it would need to return a tuple containing both values, and any subsequent operations (like `/2*a`) would have to operate on both values are return both results.

Comment: I understand. ± is like an acronym in that it stands for something and it's just a quicker way to represent that longer thing. Thank you. I'm getting the hang of programming and what it can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably "interval arithmetic" is what you are looking for.

[wiki/Interval_arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic)

[interval.sourceforge.net](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://interval.sourceforge.net/interval/index.html&ei=fqprUOv5OJCQ4gSEo4CoBA&usg=AFQjCNGZlZ2neqf-0CdBt3JSe_hoad7OFQ&sig2=j3loFaV-X1CdhMm3kD9tsA)